# Quotients of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, group-schemes, geometric-invariant-theory

It is known that $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \not \cong \mathbb{P}^2$. One way to see this is working with their respective class groups, $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, which in this case, since they are normal toric varieties are fairly easy to compute.

My question is whether we can "fix" this by identifying some points on $X =\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, that is, if there exists some free group action $\sigma \colon G \times X \to X$ ($G$ finite) such that the quotient $X/G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Forgetting the algebraic-geometry structure, the action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $X$ via permutation of elements is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$, so:

> Does this extend to an isomorphism of schemes?

Also, any references that deal with this type of quotients will be welcome, of course. Thank you.

**Note:** I wrote that the action is free because apparently this guarantees that the quotient is at least an algebraic space; the finiteness requirement guarantees that it is actually a scheme, as in the answers to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1558/quotients-of-schemes-by-free-group-actions) question.

Comment: What is the isomorphism $X/(\mathbb Z/2) \cong \mathbb P^2$?

Comment: @punctureddusk I took the result from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214612/understanding-the-cartesian-product-of-complex-projective-lines)

Comment: @user313212: In the question you referring to the covering is ramified. In fact, there are no unramified (connected) coverings over $\mathbb{P}^2$, since its fundamental group is trivial. So, $\mathbb{P}^2$ can not be identified with the quotient of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ by a FREE group action.